# JQueryUI droppable drop event fires before reverting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have a revert function so I can add some extra checks that will trigger a revert. The drop function to align the draggable with the droppable seems to fire before the draggable is reverted back to its original position.

It seems to me that this only happens if the revert function is used, as on a disabled droppable it acts normally.

```
$( ".box" ).draggable({
  revert: function(socketObj) {
    if (socketObj === false) {
      return true;
    } else {
        if ( $(this).hasClass("box") ) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  },
});

$( ".ru" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.draggable.position({
      of: $(this),
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left top'
    });
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ugywztgw/

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/ugywztgw/2/

Comment: @Parth The "return true;" is intended, that if statement is a placeholder for the extra checks I want to add to the revert function.

Comment: what is the problem now? you don't want box to come to previous position?

Comment: As I said in the question, the drop function fires before the revert happens. If you look at the jsfiddle and drag to the first droppable you'll see the behavior.

Comment: Things works perfectly. If you use droppable  then it should first call drop event If drop successful then after it reverts. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/ugywztgw/3/

Comment: The issue is that there is different behavior between the 2 droppable divs. On the first droppable div, it first re-positions the draggable to the droppable and then reverts. On the second droppable div, it reverts **without** re-positioning the draggable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is the proper behavior.

Disabled droppable is just like any other non-drop area. You'll get the same behaviour when you drop the draggable somewhere else in the window.

Think about the other users that needs to execute some logic on drop, whether it was a valid drop or not. for example a game where user is only given `n` turns to drop, whether they were valid or not, or similar scenarios. If drop event't doesn't fire at all for non-valid drops, they'll complaint that they need a way to detect drop.

Think about invoking drop handler after reverting, which is what you're asking -

That doesn't make sense at all. Drop happened first, the decision whether to revert or not was taken based on the dropped item, **after** drop. It's not like if you hover a non-valid item over a droppable it'll revert back. **Drop needs to happen**, and users need a way to identify it happened.

Id'd say this is not a bug, this is the most logical behavior targeting larger number of users. You'll need to work around for your specific scenario. How to work around depends on your specific use case.

---

In this case, you can move the code that decides whether to revert or not to the drop handler, and execute further code based on the result:

```js
$(".box").draggable({
  revert: function(elm) {
    return !elm || $(this).hasClass('invalid');
  }
});

$(".ru").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.draggable.hasClass("box")) {
      return ui.draggable.addClass("invalid");
    }
    ui.draggable.position({
      of: $(this),
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left top'
    });
  }
});

$("#ru4").droppable("option", "disabled", true);
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ru {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="containment">
  <div id='ru1' class='ru'>
    <div class="box">Drag me</div>
  </div>
  <div id='ru2' class='ru'>Drops then reverts</div>
  <div id='ru4' class='ru'>Disabled - reverts normally</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No the drop function does not fire in both scenarios as I've talked about. I've made it even more obvious in an updated fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ugywztgw/7/)

Comment: @Mike in your fiddle the drop callback does fire and the background becomes red in the case of enabled droppable... *"droppable drop event fires before reverting"* is your question title... which I as was trying to explain is the logically the expected behavior

Comment: Yes but the whole question is, why does it only fire on the 1 droppable and **NOT** the other?

Comment: @Mike because it is disabled..! It is disabled so no drop is possible..  Think of it just any other normal element because it's droppable capability is totally disabled!  Why no drop is called when you drop it in body..? becuase it is not a droppable at the moment. The disabled droppable is just like that. Isn't that simple to understand..? You can't put something into a jar which is closed, while it is closed. No dropping into jar at all since it is closed. In the other case, jar is open, you put something into it, then decides whether to take it out or not.  See the updated answer.

Comment: I thought the function that decides if it's valid would still be run on the disabled droppable, thanks TJ, that's the answer I was looking for.